# Check if a element in array exists but not perform any task javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, workflow

So I have been tasked with making a basic workflow engine. I have it checking the config file for dependencies and then performing the next function. what I would like to is check to see if the element already exists and not push it to the output array. I have tried `.includes()` and `.indexOf()` but I cant seem to get them to work.

```
const TestWorkflowConfig = {
  insertDetails: {
    dependencies: [],
    workflow: { name: "updateRow", id: 10 },
    description: "This is a test function where details need to be entered (row update)",
    data: {},
    taskName: "insertDetails",
  },

  detailsConfirmed: {
      { insertDetails: { isRequired: true; } }
dependencies: ["insertDetails"],
  workflow: { name: "updateRow", id: 10; },
description: "this is to confirm details (update row status)",
  data: {},
taskName: "detailsConfirmed",
  },

sendConfirmationEmail: {

  dependencies: ["detailsConfirmed"],
    workflow: { name: "sendEmail", id: 8; },
  description: "this is a test email to send out to confirm details (send email workflow)",
    data: { name: "james", email: "james@email.com", body: "this is a test email please ignore"; },
  taskName: "sendConfirmationEmail",
  },
};

const taskQueue = [
  {
    "processName": "sendConfirmationEmail",
    "isComplete": false
  },
  {
    "processName": "detailsConfirmed",
    "isComplete": false
  },
  {
    "processName": "insertDetails",
    "isComplete": true
  }
];
const workflowTaskQueue = [];
const config = TestWorkflowConfig;
const completedJobs = [];

for (const element of taskQueue) {
  if (element.isComplete === true) {
    completedJobs.push(element.processName);
  }
}

for (const element in config) {

  if (config[element].dependencies <= 0) {

    // I would like to check if the "config[element]" is in the completedJobs array and only push if it is not there.

    workflowTaskQueue.push({ json: config[element] });
  } else {
    const dependencies = config[element].dependencies;

    const dep = [];
    for (const el of dependencies) {
      dep.push(el);
      const result = dep.every((i) => completedJobs.includes(i));
      if (result === true) {

        //  and again I would like to check if the "config[element]" is in the completedJobs array and only push if it is not there

        workflowTaskQueue.push({ json: config[element] });
      }
    }

    console.log("taskQueue: " + taskQueue);
    console.log("completedJobs: " + completedJobs);
    console.log("output:" + workflowTaskQueue);
  }
}
```

as always any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `config[element].dependencies <= 0` should be `config[element].dependencies.length <= 0` since the property is an array. Your second check is checking `includes()` against an object, which will work only if they are references to the same object, otherwise you'll need to `find()` by a unique property like `taskName`

Comment: You might want to try [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (or `.findIndex`). These take a function as an argument so you can customize how you test each object for equality. (Note that JavaScript compares objects by reference, so two separate objects will always fail an equlity test that simply uses `==` instead of a custom function.)